# Json.NET: Converting JSON with $ element to XML

Tags: json.net

Json.NET seems to handle converting many names which would be invalid XML correctly, for example:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode("{"name!1": "test"}").OuterXml
```

Results in:

```
<name_x0021_1>test</name_x0021_1>
```

But attempting to convert the following, which passes JSONLint:

```
{"$": "test"}
```

Results in

```
Result Message: System.Xml.XmlException : The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.
```

This error message in itself seems confusing as it suggests one of the names in the JSON has a : character. There might be a good reason for this but is there a way to get this to convert to XML without throwing an exception as some APIs seem to return the "$": "...." pair.

Comment: Which version of Json.NET are you using?  8.0.1 or 8.0.2?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

This is fixed in Json.NET [9.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/9.0.1) in commit [b71ca75](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/commit/b71ca75905634db33572f554488056e8f53be8bb).

**Original Answer**

This may be a bug in Json.NET's [`XmlNodeConverter.ReadElement()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/XmlNodeConverter.cs#L1445).  Json.NET has several reserved property names, all of which begin with `$`, shown [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonTypeReflector.cs):

```
    public const string IdPropertyName = "$id";
    public const string RefPropertyName = "$ref";
    public const string TypePropertyName = "$type";
    public const string ValuePropertyName = "$value";
    public const string ArrayValuesPropertyName = "$values";
```

Then, in `ReadElement()`, there is special handling for property names that begin with a `$`:

```
    private void ReadElement(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, IXmlNode currentNode, string propertyName, XmlNamespaceManager manager)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        {
            throw JsonSerializationException.Create(reader, "XmlNodeConverter cannot convert JSON with an empty property name to XML.");
        }

        Dictionary<string, string> attributeNameValues = ReadAttributeElements(reader, manager);

        string elementPrefix = MiscellaneousUtils.GetPrefix(propertyName);

        if (propertyName.StartsWith('@'))
        {
            string attributeName = propertyName.Substring(1);
            string attributePrefix = MiscellaneousUtils.GetPrefix(attributeName);

            AddAttribute(reader, document, currentNode, attributeName, manager, attributePrefix);
        }
        else if (propertyName.StartsWith('$'))
        {
            if (propertyName == JsonTypeReflector.ArrayValuesPropertyName)
            {
                propertyName = propertyName.Substring(1);
                elementPrefix = manager.LookupPrefix(JsonNamespaceUri);
                CreateElement(reader, document, currentNode, propertyName, manager, elementPrefix, attributeNameValues);
            }
            else
            {
// Your code throws an exception going down this branch.
                string attributeName = propertyName.Substring(1);
                string attributePrefix = manager.LookupPrefix(JsonNamespaceUri);
                AddAttribute(reader, document, currentNode, attributeName, manager, attributePrefix);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            CreateElement(reader, document, currentNode, propertyName, manager, elementPrefix, attributeNameValues);
        }
    }
```

I *suspect* the `propertyName.StartsWith('$')` branch should only be taken for reserved property names, meaning the method should look like:

```
    private void ReadElement(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, IXmlNode currentNode, string propertyName, XmlNamespaceManager manager)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        {
            throw JsonSerializationException.Create(reader, "XmlNodeConverter cannot convert JSON with an empty property name to XML.");
        }

        Dictionary<string, string> attributeNameValues = ReadAttributeElements(reader, manager);

        if (propertyName.StartsWith('@'))
        {
            string attributeName = propertyName.Substring(1);
            string attributePrefix = MiscellaneousUtils.GetPrefix(attributeName);

            AddAttribute(reader, document, currentNode, attributeName, manager, attributePrefix);
        }
        else if (propertyName == JsonTypeReflector.ArrayValuesPropertyName)
        {
            propertyName = propertyName.Substring(1);
            var elementPrefix = manager.LookupPrefix(JsonNamespaceUri);
            CreateElement(reader, document, currentNode, propertyName, manager, elementPrefix, attributeNameValues);
        }
        else if (propertyName == JsonTypeReflector.IdPropertyName
            || propertyName == JsonTypeReflector.RefPropertyName
            || propertyName == JsonTypeReflector.TypePropertyName
            || propertyName == JsonTypeReflector.ValuePropertyName)
        {
            string attributeName = propertyName.Substring(1);
            string attributePrefix = manager.LookupPrefix(JsonNamespaceUri);
            AddAttribute(reader, document, currentNode, attributeName, manager, attributePrefix);
        }
        else
        {
            var elementPrefix = MiscellaneousUtils.GetPrefix(propertyName);
            CreateElement(reader, document, currentNode, propertyName, manager, elementPrefix, attributeNameValues);
        }
    }
```

(Honestly, the handling of `"$value"` looks suspect also, since the value of a polymorphic property could be any JSON object.)

You might want to [report an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues).

In the meantime, you could load your JSON into a `JToken`, manually remap names beginning with `$`, then convert to an `XmlDocument` like so:

```
var token = JToken.Parse(json);

token.RenameReplaceProperties(s => (s.StartsWith("$") && !JsonExtensions.IsReserved(s) ? XmlConvert.EncodeName(s) : s));

var xml = token.ToXmlNode();
```

Using the extension methods:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    const string IdPropertyName = "$id";
    const string RefPropertyName = "$ref";
    const string TypePropertyName = "$type";
    const string ValuePropertyName = "$value";
    const string ArrayValuesPropertyName = "$values";

    public static bool IsReserved(string s)
    {
        return s == IdPropertyName || s == RefPropertyName || s == TypePropertyName || s == ValuePropertyName || s == ArrayValuesPropertyName;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<JToken> DescendantsAndSelf(this JToken root)
    {
        var container = root as JContainer;
        if (container != null)
            return container.DescendantsAndSelf();
        else if (root != null)
            return new[] { root };
        else
            return Enumerable.Empty<JToken>();
    }

    public static JProperty RenameReplace(this JProperty property, string name)
    {
        if (property == null || name == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var value = property.Value;
        property.Value = null;
        var newProperty = new JProperty(name, value);
        property.Replace(newProperty);
        return newProperty;
    }

    public static JToken RenameReplaceProperties(this JToken root, Func<string, string> map)
    {
        var query = from property in root.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JProperty>()
                    let name = map(property.Name)
                    where name != property.Name && name != null
                    select new KeyValuePair<JProperty, string>(property, name);
        foreach (var pair in query.ToList())
        {
            var newProperty = pair.Key.RenameReplace(pair.Value);
            if (pair.Key == root)
                root = newProperty;
        }
        return root;
    }

    public static XmlDocument ToXmlNode(this JToken root)
    {
        using (var reader = root.CreateReader())
            return DeserializeXmlNode(reader);
    }

    public static XmlDocument DeserializeXmlNode(JsonReader reader)
    {
        return DeserializeXmlNode(reader, null, false);
    }

    public static XmlDocument DeserializeXmlNode(JsonReader reader, string deserializeRootElementName, bool writeArrayAttribute)
    {
        var converter = new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter() { DeserializeRootElementName = deserializeRootElementName, WriteArrayAttribute = writeArrayAttribute };
        var jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new JsonConverter[] { converter } });
        return (XmlDocument)jsonSerializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(XmlDocument));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have submitted it as an issue - https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/844

Comment: @chrisb - you are welcome.  If the question is answered please do [mark it as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow).